# UBUNTU 14.04 No audio is being produced?

Tags: drivers, sound, realtek

I earlier had a problem of low level of audio.
so I tried installing Realtek audio codecs- Linux version,(software installation)

- [Realtek High Definition Audio Codecs](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=14&PFid=24&Level=4&Conn=3)
- [Realtek AC'97 Audio Codecs](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=14&PFid=23&Level=4&Conn=3)

but after following the procedure suggested by Realtek,
I could not know whether the setup was successful or not....
after that NO SOUND is coming from my system speakers? Need help..

Comment: See if channels are muted with alsamixer or pavucontrol. If they are, unmute them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the drivers were made for kernel 2.4/2.6, which is extremely out dated. And are you sure you have a realtek sound card? But anyway see [SoundTroubleshootingProcedure](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure).